# How to solve the error Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a Node API with Express but using the JSON file as persistent data.
During the build of my routes I'm getting the error:
`Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`
 What I want is to create a new product and that be validated by my middleware as follow:

```
// Express
const express = require("express");
// Router
const router = express.Router();
// Product model
const product = require("../../models/product");
// Validations middleware
const {
    validateRules
} = require("../../middlewares/validatorRules.middleware");
const {
    productValidationRulesPOST
} = require("../../middlewares/validators.middleware");

// Add a new product
// Validate the rules before start
router.post("/", productValidationRulesPOST, validateRules, (req, res) => {
    // product
    product
        // Using the model to create a Product
        .createProduct(req.body)
        .then( data =>
            // OK product is created
            res.status(201).json({
                message: `The product #${data.id} has been created`,
                content: data
            })
        )
        // Error product not created
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ message: err.message }));
});

// Routes
module.exports = router;
```

I believe I have an issue with my middleware `productValidationRulesPOST`

```
// Adding body module of express validator
const { body } = require("express-validator");

// Product fields validations
const productValidationRulesPOST = () => {
    return [
        // Name must be min 3 characters and required
        body("name", "Name is required and 3 characters at least")
            .exists()
            .isLength({ min: 3 }),
        // Description must be min 10 characters and required
        body("description", "Description is required and 10 characters at least")
            .exists()
            .isLength({ min: 10 }),
        // Brand required and min length 3
        body("brand", "3 characters at least")
            .exists()
            .isLength({ min: 3 }),
        // Image URL not required
        body("imageUrl").optional(),
        // Price as a number and required
        body("price", "Price is required")
            .exists()
            .isNumeric(),
        // Category not required min length 3
        body("category", "3 characters at least")
            .optional()
            .isLength({ min: 3 })
    ];
};

// Exports the required methods
module.exports = {
    productValidationRulesPOST
}
```

Or maybe on this one:

```
const { matchedData, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const validateRules = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        req.matchedData = matchedData(req);
        return next();
    }

    const extractedErrors = [];
    errors.array().map(err => extractedErrors.push({ [err.param]: err.msg }));

    return res.status(422).json({
        errors: extractedErrors
    });
};

module.exports = validateRules;
```

The thing is I cannot move forward as I cannot get a clue why I'm getting the error and cannot really understand if the issue can be with the 1st or 2sd middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your `validateRules` because with `express-validator`, you can pass `productValidationRulesPOST` as a middleware but validations are done inside `callback`

```
  router.post("/", productValidationRulesPOST, (req, res) => {

      validateRules(req,res)

});
```

**UPDATE**

```
const validateRules = (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        req.matchedData = matchedData(req);
        // Return true or something that makes sense
    }

    const extractedErrors = [];
    errors.array().map(err => extractedErrors.push({ [err.param]: err.msg }));

    return res.status(422).json({
        errors: extractedErrors
    });
};
```

I'm not really sure if this will work but it makes sense to remove `next()` as you are not using this function as a middleware, so it's just a plain javascript `exported function`

Comment: But then I need to do all the same or i have to do like `.product`?

Comment: The problem is that testing with postman is giving that there is no response now after that modification that why I'm asking what else should be changed to make it work

Comment: I'm getting no response from server actually

Comment: By the way that not work for me as validateRules giving an error as it is not a function

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
router.post("/", productValidationRulesPOST, validateRules, (req, res) => {
 ...
})
```

for:

```
router.post("/", productValidationRulesPOST(), validateRules, (req, res) => {
 ...
})
```